# Ignore files within the 'Delete Files Task'

Tags: azure-devops, tfsbuild, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

As part of my install scripts for Visual Studio Online (VSO / VSTS) I delete the files in my directory shortly after uninstalling the services.

We have configuration files and logs that I'd like to preserve but everytime I try to tell the 'Delete Files Task' to ignore those files it deletes them anyway.

What I want is for ALL files in the Bifrost directory to be deleted except for

- The Logs folder
- App.Connections.Config
- App.Queues.Config

Can someone help please?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- If the files you want to delete are located in the agent folder or the subfolder of the agent machine, you can use **[Delete Files](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/utility/delete-files) Task**. Because the **Source Folder** of Delete Files Task can only be specified for the agent machine.
- If the files you want to delete are located on another remote machine, you should use **Powershell task** or **[RemoteDelete](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=saeidbabaei.remotedeletesaeid) task** to delete the files.

  For powershell task, there are many powershell script on the web to delete files from remote machine.

  For RemoteDelete task, you can set as below:

  Input your remote machine’s IP, username and password.

  Path: the directory for `Bifrost` folder, such as `D:\test\Bitfrost`

  Include Items: folders and files you want to delete and separate with comma (`,`). Such as delete folder `temp` and file `*.txt`, you can specify with `temp,*.txt`

  Exculde Items: folders and files you want to keep. For you situation, you 
  should specify as `Logs,App.Connections.Config,App.Queues.Config`

  **Note:** the **Include Items** option can't leave empty or use `**`, otherwise it will delete all the files and folders in `Bifrost`.

Comment: i am also working on the same logic need to delete whole folder except 3 folder, how i can use 'Delete File' ??